# Bootstrap 3 select input form style

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a select dropdown menu similar to other inputs in a bootstrap 3 form. see [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/liS98UfubD8BU8DT2ASI/)
[image]

This is in the header:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/vitality-orange.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

How can I make it look in similar style as the other types of inputs?
This is the code currently displayed:

```
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Gender</label>
            <select id="gender" class="form-control">
                <option value="male">Man</option>
                <option value="female">Woman</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Indeed we don't know how it looks now!, in bootstrap it seems normal! But you should consult the theme makers since vitality seems to be a paid product or provide us what you have now (as a result) and what you want precisely otherwise this question remains ambiguous.

Comment: The theme doesn't style `select`, so make your own styling for it: http://codeply.com/go/5RT3pl4Dff

Answer (score 0):

This [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/OAvBmn3h25u3e5oMUUIn/) works very fine with no changes.

Problem was with your style
.

```
floating-label-form-group label {
  /* display: block; */
```

just removing `display: block;` everything works fine.

Comment: Yes I do, I also added in the question the header code. I know that when I inspect the in put element, I notice both css files in use (bootstrap and vitality)

Comment: you can be specific by creating  plunker/jsfiddler for it? Needs to take a look, for this kind of issues.

Comment: This should be comment.  You have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: I just did Shankar. Please let me know if you are not able to see my updated plunker

Comment: Which browser you are using? I can see the right behaviour.

Comment: I am trying both chrome and firefox, on Windows 7. Both are not working for me. The button is barely clickable (you would have to click at its bottom in our to function)

Answer (score 0):

This solution did the job. Thanks Skelly and Shankar:

> The theme doesn't style select, so make your own styling for it:
>   [codeply.com/go/5RT3pl4Dff](http://codeply.com/go/5RT3pl4Dff) – Skelly

Comment: Instead of just having a link to your code, you should put it in your answer.